# How to connect to server (not database)

Tags: c#, sql, tcp, visual-studio-2013

I have been coding applications that run multiple and complex queries to databases for years. I have also created a chat server that forms a server - client connection.

My question is, is it possible, are there any benefits and how would one go about connecting an application to a server to use the database rather than running individual queries?

If you are running multiple queries on multiple databases as well as pulling and pushing data via ftp from one server, can you connect to that server alone and perform all tasks within one connection?

Comment: Are you simply asking "can the clients talk to a central service rather than talking to the database"? if so: yes, absolutely; that would be SOA, and is pretty common. I confess I have no idea what role ftp would play in a chat or database scenario.

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell. is this what you are refering to with 'SOA'? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480021.aspx

Comment: @NicholasMordecai broadly yes, although I wouldn't constrain the definition to technologies such as WSDL (which that article does); by SOA I mean just about anything where there is a service layer of some kind, with the clients talking to that service on **any** protocol.

Comment: Ohh okay, do you have a link to hand where I might start reading up on this?

Comment: here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156544(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it should be emphasized that WCF or WSDL is not an important feature here; it could be JSON over http, or text over a raw socket